# Putty SSH Tunnel used in Virtualbox as Network-Adapter

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, proxy

I have a Putty SSH Tunnel through a firewall, which works fine. Localhost:8080 proxies everything to the other end.

Now I want a VirtualBox VM use the tunnel as standard eth adapter (I don't want to set up proxy settings in the VM).

I googled and found only a guide for a linux host machine (http://ku1ik.com/2011/11/12/tunnel-vm-network-ssh.html), but I am using Windows as a host. The VM is linux and the other end of the ssh-tunnel is also linux.

How do I setup a tun/tap adapter, or what else can I do?

Thanks

EDIT: I also tried "proxifier", though it seems like a bad solution for me. But I cannot configure it to work with VBox.

Comment: You may wish to jump into the mod chat and ask for your two accounts to be merged. That will make edits and commenting a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

For the adapter, you can install [TAP-windows driver](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html#packages-and-ports) from OpenVPN project.